# Not able to launch Spark cluster in Standalone mode with start-all.sh

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark and I am trying to install Spark Standalone to a 3 node cluster. I have done password-less SSH from master to other nodes.

I have tried the following config changes

- Updated the hostnames for 2 nodes in conf/slaves.sh file.  Created spark-env.sh file and updated the SPARK_MASTER_IP with the master URL Also, tried
  updating the spark.master value in the spark-defaults.conf file

  Snapshot of conf/slaves.sh

  ```
  # A Spark Worker will be started on each of the machines listed below.
  Spark-WorkerNode1.hadoop.com
  Spark-WorkerNode2.hadoop.com
  ```

Snapshot of spark-defaults.conf

```
    # Example:
      spark.master                     spark://Spark-Master.hadoop.com:7077
```

But when I try to start the cluster by running the start-all.sh on the master, it does not recognize the worker nodes and start the cluster as local.

It does not give any error, the log files shows Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' and Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on the master.

I have tried to run start-master and start-slave script on individual nodes and it seems to work fine. I can see 2 workers in the web UI. I am using spark 1.6.0

Can somebody please help me with what I am missing while trying to run start-all?

Comment: Please provide the logs. Without these we can only guess.

Comment: having similar issue. any resolution to this? works with manual worker attachments to master but when I run `start-all.sh`, the worker nodes show up in master UI but the links for the worker nodes `<ip>:8081` don't work.

Answer (score 1):

> Snapshot of conf/slaves.sh

The file should named `slaves` without extension.